# C++ function trigger C# function

Tags: c#, delegates, c++-cli, unmanaged, managed

Basically my code is looks like below

**Managed.dll**

**Managed.cs**

```
class MyManagedClass
{
public ShowMessage()
{
System.out.println("My Message");
}
}
```

**Wrapper.dll**

```
ref class Wrapper

    {

    };
```

**Native.lib**

```
class NativeClass
{
public:
void NativeMessage()
{
cout<<"Print Message";
}

}
```

**Main**

```
void main
{
NativeClass ob;
ob.NativeMessage();
}
```

my issue is whenever the "ob.NativeMessage();" called, somehow MyManagedClass::ShowMessage()  has to be triggered.

And more impotent Native.lib linked in Wrapper.dll and Wrapper.dll referenced in Managed.dll.

Can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running strictly from a C++ environment, you will want to [host a .NET runtime in your C++ application](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CppHostCLR-e6581ee0). If you're running from a .NET environment, that part is already done and you will need to pass a delegate to the C++ code to be called later (this, by the way, is fraught with problems as the .NET runtime up to at least version 3.0 can and will garbage collect delegates out from under you).